# How to get response from restlet ClientResource?

Tags: java, android, rest, http-post, restlet

This may be easy one, but I am confused.

I am trying to do HTTP POST on a server using Android Restlet, and read the reply returned from the server.

I created form using:

```
Form form = new Form
form.add("msg" ,"This is my message");
```

Now, I have clientResource as follows:

```
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("www.example.com/my-http-post-url/");
```

Now, I am doing HTTP Post as:

```
Representation response=null;

try{

 response= clientResource.post(form.getWebRepresentation(null));
 System.out.println("Got response !! , response : " + response.getText());
 System.out.println( "Got Context: " + clientResource.getContext() );
 System.out.println( "Got Response: " + clientResource.getResponse());
 System.out.println( "Got Resonse Attribute : " + clientResource.getResponseAttributes() );
 System.out.println( "Got Resonse Entity: " + clientResource.getResponseEntity() );

}catch(Exception e){

e.printStackTrace();

}
```

I found out that the code is going inside try, but its printing :

```
I/org.restlet(  493): Starting the default HTTP client
I/System.out(  493): Got response !! , response : null
I/System.out(  493): Got Context: null
I/System.out(  493): Got Response: HTTP/1.1 - OK (200) - OK
I/System.out(  493): Got Resonse Attribute : {org.restlet.http.headers=[(Date,Sun, 22 Jul 2012 22:14:03 GMT), (Server,WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.1+), (Vary,Authorization), (Content-Type,application/json; charset=utf-8)]}
I/System.out(  493): Got Resonse Entity: [application/json,UTF-8]
```

I tried sniffing the data, to see if the server is replying or not, I am confident that server is sending the response content.

Can anyone tell me, how can I find out the response content send by the server?

Comment: I'm also having this problem, in just plain Java SE (not android).  It's like responseRepresentation.getText() doesn't work.  It's always null.  I've "sniffed" the connection, and the server is sending back valid JSON in the body of the response.  I don't get it.

Comment: I ended up using simple HTTP POST. :-/ it worked absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're using client-side support of Restlet the right way. The response content should be contained within the response representation...

The first step is to call your REST service outside Android to see the exact response content. Can you try to do this using restclient (http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) or curl?

Thierry

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

I have something similar to this right now:

```
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(url);
Request request = new Request(Method.POST, url);

clientResource.setRequest(request);

    Form form = new Form();

    form.set("foo", "barValue");

    org.restlet.representation.Representation   response = clientResource.post(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Representation responseEntity = clientResource.getResponseEntity();

    JsonRepresentation jsonRepresentation = new JsonRepresentation(responseEntity);

    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonRepresentation.getJsonObject();
    String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObject);

    if (jsonObject.has("errorString"))
    {
        String error = jsonObject.optString("errorString");
    }
```